# Getting started with fzf on Arch Linux

Tags: bash, vim

I just installed [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) on Arch Linux 4.13.11 using `pacman -S fzf`.

From Bash, I can call `fzf` which lets me select files (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>) in the current directory and its subdirectories.

This is nice, but I'd like to have Bash integration of some sort.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Default Bash key bindings

Using `whereis fzf`, I found `fzf`'s files for Bash integration in `/usr/share/fzf`:

```
completion.bash
key-bindings.bash
```

After [`source`](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)ing both files, this enables a couple of key bindings for Bash: For example, I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> to search files in the current directory and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to search my command history.

For finding and changing to a directory, there's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.

To make these key bindings persistent, I added them to my `.bashrc`:

```
source /usr/share/fzf/completion.bash && source /usr/share/fzf/key-bindings.bash
```

### Customization

A customization I find useful is showing a file preview when using `fzf` (I put that in my `.bashrc` as well):

```
# When selecting files with fzf, we show file content with syntax highlighting,
# or without highlighting if it's not a source file. If the file is a directory,
# we use tree to show the directory's contents.
# We only load the first 200 lines of the file which enables fast previews
# of large text files.
# Requires highlight and tree: pacman -S highlight tree
export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--preview '(highlight -O ansi -l {} 2> /dev/null ||
cat {} || tree -C {}) 2> /dev/null | head -200'"
```

#### Path completion

Out of the box, `fzf` supports fuzzy path completion for a couple of [hard-coded](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/536) commands like `cd`, `ls`, and `vim`. To see a list of those commands, run `complete | grep _fzf`.

For example, entering `vim **` <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Bash starts a fuzzy search in the current directory and opens the selected file with Vim<sup>1</sup>.

This is pretty useful, but I'd like to open, for example, PDFs the same way. You can enable this by adding the following line to `.bashrc`:

```
_fzf_setup_completion path zathura
```

Here, [`zathura`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zathura) is my PDF viewer; you can substitute it with the document viewer of your choice.

Note that fuzzy path completion works for all paths, not only the current directory:

```
vim ~/**
```

and then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will fuzzy-search a file under your home directory and then open it in Vim.

The [readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/#user-content-supported-commands) of `fzf` gives more examples of enabling path completion.

#### Completion of other things than paths

`fzf` isn't limited to fuzzy-searching files. For example:

- Entering `ssh **` <kbd>Tab</kbd> presents you with a list of hostnames and IP addresses from `~/.ssh/config` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.
- With `kill **` <kbd>Tab</kbd> you can end running programs by entering parts of the program's name.

You can also add fuzzy-searching for processes to any command that requires a process ID:

```
_fzf_setup_completion proc top pmap pstree
```

Try `top -p **` <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select a process and watch its resource usage via [`top`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/top.1).

This customization includes [`pmap`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pmap.1) and [`pstree`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pstree.1.en) to make those commands more convenient: Fuzzy-search for a process name instead of entering the process ID.

### Vim integration

Here are some key bindings from my `.vimrc` to use `fzf` inside a Vim session:

```
" Search and switch buffers
nmap <leader>b :Buffers<cr>
" Find files by name under the current directory
nmap <leader>f :Files<cr>
" Find files by name under the home directory
nmap <leader>h :Files ~/<cr>
" Search content in the current file
nmap <leader>l :BLines<cr>
" Search content in the current file and in files under the current directory
nmap <leader>g :Ag<cr>
```

Prerequisite for all that is the [`fzf` Vim plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim); I installed it with [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) by putting this in my `.vimrc`:

```
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
```

and then calling `:PlugInstall` from Vim.

[Here is a list](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#user-content-commands) of `fzf` commands you can call from Vim.

You can also have path completion when writing text in Vim:

```
imap <c-x><c-f> <plug>(fzf-complete-path)
```

Try it out by writing "~/" in your file opened in Vim and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. Select a file by fuzzy searching and its path is added at Vim's cursor position. See the [readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#user-content-mappings) on those mappings for more.

#### Search files of project

Especially when working on software, I like to switch between files of a given project. Assuming that the project is versioned using Git, here's a binding that will fuzzy-search file **names** inside the project and open the selected file:

```
nmap <leader>gr :GFiles! --cached --others --exclude-standard<cr>
```

See [this discussion](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/837) on how to also fuzzy-search file **content** inside the current Git repo.

### Going further

For a powerful combination of `fzf`, Vim, and Tmux, check out [Keegan Lowenstein's blog post](https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/tmux-and-vim) (I got the `--preview` configuration from there).

[Here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Configuring-shell-key-bindings) are some ideas on how to configure `fzf`'s shell integration.

You can find more examples of `fzf` configuration in [`fzf`'s readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#user-content-usage) and in its [wiki](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples).

<sub>1 If you find yourself fuzzy-searching files and then opening them in Vim a lot, you can create a key binding for that using [this piece of `.bashrc`](https://gist.github.com/mb720/86144b670599c0eab331cd2f48bd23b9).</sub>